# WildFly Jboss 26.1.3.Final ¿alguién sabe algo? del error newValue is Null

Tags: ubuntu, jboss, wildfly

Tengo problemas con mi servidor de aplicaciones WildFly 26.1.3.Final, al ingresar a la configuración, subistemas, Datasources & Drivers, me arroja el error de newVale is Null, en las versiones anteriores se habla de Hal Management Consol pero ya aplique esa corrección y no funcionó.
Les dejo imagen del error.
Por cierto estoy usando Ubuntu 22.04LTS y Java 11.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Okey lo siento.

Comment: Mi problema específico es que puedo subir drivers de conexión al servidor, pero cuando voy a consultarlos me arroja el error "newVale is null". Ese mismo error me sucede cuando intento agregar el Datasources. En el servidor voy a Configuration ->Subsystems -> DAtaources & Drivers -> Datasources -> Add Datasource y en ese momento me muestra el dichoso error.

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que las respuestas a comentarios, aclaraciones, logs, pruebas adicionales, van todas en la pregunta que puedes [edit]. Acá abajo se pierden las cosas y los logs son ilegibles, por ejemplo. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.